# Adding/subtracting two numeric strings

Tags: go, math, biginteger

I have two variables with big numbers set as strings:

```
var numA = "340282366920938463463374607431768211456"
var numB = "17014118346046923173168730371588410572"
```

I want to be able to add and subtract these kinds of large string numbers in Go.

I know I need to use `math/big` but I still can not for the life of me figure out how, so any example help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use [`big.NewInt()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#NewInt) to create a new `big.Int` value initialized with an `int64` value. It returns you a pointer (`*big.Int`). Alternatively you could simply use the builtin [`new()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#new) function to allocate a `big.Int` value which will be `0` like this: `new(big.Int)`, or since `big.Int` is a struct type, a simple [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) would also do: `&big.Int{}`.

Once you have a value, you may use [`Int.SetString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetString) to parse and set a number given as `string`. You can pass the base of the string number, and it also returns you a `bool` value indicating if parsing succeeded.

Then you may use [`Int.Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Add) and [`Int.Sub()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Sub) to calculate the sum and difference of 2 `big.Int` numbers. Note that `Add()` and `Sub()` write the result into the receiver whose method you call, so if you need the numbers (operands) unchanged, use another `big.Int` value to calculate and store the result.

See this example:

```
numA := "340282366920938463463374607431768211456"
numB := "17014118346046923173168730371588410572"

ba, bb := big.NewInt(0), big.NewInt(0)
if _, ok := ba.SetString(numA, 10); !ok {
    panic("invalid numA")
}
if _, ok := bb.SetString(numB, 10); !ok {
    panic("invalid numB")
}

sum := big.NewInt(0).Add(ba, bb)
fmt.Println("a + b =", sum)

diff := big.NewInt(0).Sub(ba, bb)
fmt.Println("a - b =", diff)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TcNqe5a1xSB)):

```
a + b = 357296485266985386636543337803356622028
a - b = 323268248574891540290205877060179800884
```